# How to convert at jpg image to tensors in react native?

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, computer-vision

I cannot get my jpg image converted to tensors, the root problem is because I cannot convert the jpg image to UINT8ARRAY. If I directly pass the jpg image to the tensor conversion function it will give an error of no SOI found.

```
const response = await fetch(imageLink, {}, { isBinary: true });
console.log(response);
const rawImageData = await response.arrayBuffer();
console.log(rawImageData);
```

From running the code above, I get an output for the fetch function, but when I gave it the arrayBuffer() function it returned nothing. How do I fix this, I would also happily accept and appreciate any other methods to solve this issue.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqr0V.png)